# change of one user not reflect to another user on jsp

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, jsp

I have a jsp page one which i have four images once the user click any of them the image change to another one and this is must be reflect to all the users using that website on a page refresh.....I am not want to use any database.

Here is my code

```
<head><title>First JSP</title></head>
   <body>      
</form>
<%! public static int bulbStatus = 0; 
    public static int tubeStatus=0;
public static  int fanStatus=0;
public static  int acStatus=0;
%>
  <%  
// HelloResource.counter 
/*if(bulbStatus==1)
{
    bulbStatus=0;
}*/
//fetch values from database if value is 1 then image will be bulbon else buloff
//if(request.getParameter("BULB.x")!=null)
if(bulbStatus==0)
{

%>
<%
  bulbStatus++;
%>
<form action="index.jsp">
<div id="NW">
    <input type="image" src="images/pic_bulboff.png"  align="center" id="image1" name="BULB" value="bulb"></input>
</div>
</from>

<%
} 
else
   {
    %>
<% bulbStatus=0; %>
   <form action="index.jsp">
       <div id="NW">
            <input type="image" src="images/pic_bulbon.png"      align="center"     id="image1" name="BULB" value="bulb"></input><p></p>
            <input type="hidden" name="fieldOfBulb" value="1"></input>
        </div>
    </form>

    <%
    }
    if(tubeStatus==0)
    {
   %> 
   <%
      tubeStatus++;
    %>
   <form action="index.jsp">
   <div id="NE">
        <input type="image" src= "images/lampoff.png" align="center"     name="TUBE" value="tube" id="image2"></input>
        <input type="hidden" name="fieldOfTube" value="1"></input>
    </div>
   </form>
  <%  }
    else
    {
  %>
  <%
      tubeStatus=0;
%>
  <form action="index.jsp">
        <div id="NE">
        <input type="image" src= "images/lampon.png" align="center"      name="TUBE" value="tube" id="image2"></input>
        <input type="hidden" name="fieldOfTube" value="1"></input>
    </div>
  </form>
  <%
    }
   if(fanStatus==0)
    {
   %>
   <form action="index.jsp">
        <div id="SW">
    <input type="image" src="images/Fanoff.png" align="center" id="image3" name="AC" value="ac"></input>
    <input type="hidden" name="fieldOfAC" value="1"></input>
    </div>
    </form>
   <%
    }
    else
    {
   %>
   <form action="index.jsp">
   <div id="SW">
        <input type="image" src="images/Fanon.png" align="center"     id="image3" name="AC" value="ac"></input>
        <input type="hidden" name="fieldOfAC" value="1"></input>
    </div>
    </form>
 <%     
     }
    if(acStatus==0)
    {
   %>
        <div id="SE">
        <input type="image" src="images/pic_bulboff.gif" align="center"     id="image4" name="FAN" value="fan"></input>
        <input type="hidden" name="fieldOfFAN" value="1"></input>
    </div>
    <%
    }
     else
    {
    %>

    <div id="SE">
        <input type="image" src="images/pic_bulboff.gif" align="center"     id="image4" name="FAN" value="fan"></input>
        <input type="hidden" name="fieldOfFAN" value="1"></input>
    </div>
<%
    }
%>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You can use application implicit object to create a new attribute that store the image state

Comment: You can use a static map on serverside or context

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ can u send me the code

Comment: @MayankChoudhary Don't have codes now. That's an idea.